# "Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)" when pushing to the remote git server from gitlab

Tags: git, push, gitlab

I started gitlab with:

```
rvmsudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

When I create a new project, I get the remote repo url:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:12035/root/my_project.git

(so not the default 22 ssh port, but 12035)
```

So when I try to push it to the gitlab:

```
git push --verbose -u origin master
```

Then I get:

```
Pushing to ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:12035/root/my_project.git
/home/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
        from /home/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
        from /home/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
        from /home/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
        from /home/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
        from /home/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
        from /home/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:62:in `get'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:17:in `allowed?'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:60:in `validate_access'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:23:in `exec'
        from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I have two users: a normal one: `kai` and the `git` for gitlab. But the `gitlab` user has no `.ssh` directory. But I already added the ssh-key from the remote machine from where I am trying to push to the gitlab. The key is added to the `~/.ssh/config` as:

```
Host gitlab.mydomain.com
        User admin@local.host
        # User Administrator
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_rsa
```

## P.S.

already looked into all similar questions here related to the error. but either didn't not get the answers or they didn't help

## Update:

the lines in the `/var/log/auth.log` for the last `git push` attempt:

```
Oct 13 06:53:04 80-69-77-159 sudo:  kai : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/git/gitlab ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/less /var/log/auth.log
Oct 13 06:53:04 80-69-77-159 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by kai(uid=0)
```

So all the possible users appear there. What does it mean?

Update 2:

I checked the gitlab-shell with:

```
sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
```

and got the same:

```
http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I changed then the `gitlab_url` to `https` in `config.yml`:

```
sudo -u git -H nano /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml

gitlab_url: "http://gitlab.udesk.org/" -> gitlab_url: "https://gitlab.udesk.org/"
```

Now I get from the `sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check`:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

What could be now the problem?

## Update 3:

Then I changed the `self_signed_cert: false` to `self_signed_cert: true` in `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml`.

Now I get from the `sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check`:

```
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
```

But still cannot push:

```
Pushing to ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:12035/root/my_project.git
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

## Update 4:

Now I noticed that the test ssh line now works:

```
> ssh -vT -p 12035 git@gitlab.mydomain.com

debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitlab.mydomain.com ([x.x.x.x]:12035).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Welcome to GitLab, Administrator!
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3264, received 3248 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4782.6, received 4759.2
debug1: Exit status 0
```

## Update 5:

in the `/home/git/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log` the corresponding line to the `git push --verbose -u origin master` is:

```
W, [2013-10-13T15:18:05.276231 #24654]  WARN -- : gitlab-shell: Access denied for git command <git-receive-pack '/root/myproject.git'> by user with key key-1.
```

What could be still the problem?

Comment: Is it an nginx config issue, as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3384#issuecomment-15457287 (or https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/20#issuecomment-15333049)?

Comment: I think it is not. I have now not the ` Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)` but `Access denied.`. I don't know which logs I should look now

Answer (score 2):

By default unicorn is configured to listening on `127.0.0.1:8080(/home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb)`, so `gitlab_url` needs to set as `http://yourURL:8080/`

Answer (score 1):

After I executed (on the server with gitlab):

```
> pwd # just to get context
    /home/git/gitlab

> sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys clear
> sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

then removed git remote and added it back again (on the local server with git repo to push to gitlab):

```
> git remote remove origin
> git remote add origin ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:12035/root/myproject.git
```

Then tried to push:

```
> git push --verbose -u origin master

Pushing to ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:12035/root/myproject.git
Counting objects: 401, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (289/289), done.
Writing objects: 100% (401/401), 1.05 MiB | 98.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 401 (delta 127), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:12035/root/myproject.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
```

Now:

```
> cat /home/git/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log

I, [2013-10-13T15:38:49.332477 #24935]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-receive-pack /home/git/repositories/'/root/myproject.git'> for user with key key-1.
I, [2013-10-13T15:40:00.037092 #24958]  INFO -- : Update head in project root/myproject.git to <master>.
```

I don't know what the real problem was here, but trying to investigate it step by step helped (first fixing the gitlab_url problem, then getting ssh working with the repo, and finally getting the git working properly). I hope these steps could help to solve some similar problems (e.g. named in the updates)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but for the general internet knowledge base.. Got this error in the latest version of gitlab setup, with a proxy virtual host in apache2, but also applies for nginx.

Ok, got the same issue - and here is how I solved it;

in /home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb

find the lines

```
# listen on both a Unix domain socket and a TCP port,
# we use a shorter backlog for quicker failover when busy
listen "/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket", :backlog => 64
listen "127.0.0.1:8080", :tcp_nopush => true
```

Change the last line to

```
listen "0.0.0.0:8080", :tcp_nopush => true
```

so it accepts connections not just from the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Again, in the hope that this might be useful to someone, somewhere; I had this same problem and none of the suggested solutions worked for me.  Specifically, I do not care about HTTPS and my GitLab is not proxied behind Apache.

My gitlab-shell's config had `gitlab_url: http://hostname:9999/`.  My gitlab/config/unicorn.rb had `listen "10.80.40.169:9999"`.  So, I just changed the `gitlab_url` to match unicorn.rb (`gitlab_url: http://10.80.40.169:9999/`) and everything works.